# Doctrine --- search

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

we use zend frame work and  doctrine data base.
now my problem is i want to search a string (for example: testin'g) a string with "single quotes".
Doctrine query fails to retrives data for the query with joins and works fine with normal query with out joins.

my method is

```
public function getNewsListGrid($campid,$currentPage,$resultsPerPage,$quickSearchType,$queryv,$sortName,$sortOrder,$letterPressed)
{
    $query = new Doctrine_Query();
    $whereCond ='';
    $where='eng.id='.$campid;
    $select='';
    $search = '';

    if($letterPressed == 'All')
    {
        $where .="";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Radian6')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.news_type = 1";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Google News')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.news_type = 3";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Google Blogs')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.news_type = 4";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Hide Twitter')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.url NOT LIKE '%twitter.com%'";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Hide Facebook')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.url NOT LIKE '%facebook.com%'";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Hide Facebook-twitter')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.url NOT LIKE '%twitter.com%' AND c.url NOT LIKE '%facebook.com%'";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Show Twitter')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.url LIKE '%twitter.com%'";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'Show Facebook')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.url LIKE '%facebook.com%'";
    }
    else if($letterPressed == 'show Facebook-twitter')
    {
        $where .=" AND c.url  LIKE '%twitter.com%' OR c.url LIKE '%facebook.com%'";
    }


    if($queryv!='' && (trim($letterPressed) != 'Law' && trim($letterPressed) != 'Ls Translate')){

        $search = ' c.title like "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($queryv).'%" ';
    }

    $select='c.id, c.campaign_id, c.title as title, c.domain, c.news_type,c.url, c.active, c.article_date, c.created_date, c.modified_date, t.language_id, t.tr_translated_date, t.tr_translated_by, t.translation_state, t.tr_title, t.raw_title';
    if(trim($letterPressed) == 'Original')
    {
        $select='c.id, c.campaign_id, c.title as title, c.domain, c.news_type,c.url, c.active, c.article_date, c.created_date, c.modified_date, t.language_id, t.tr_translated_date, t.tr_translated_by, t.translation_state';
    }
    if(trim($letterPressed) == 'Law')
    {
        $select='c.id, c.campaign_id, c.domain, c.news_type,c.url, c.active,c.article_date, c.created_date, c.modified_date, t.raw_title as title, t.language_id, t.tr_translated_date, t.tr_translated_by, t.translation_state';
        if($queryv!='')
            $search = ' t.raw_title like "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($queryv).'%" ';
    }
    if(trim($letterPressed) == 'Ls Translate')
    {
        $select='c.id, c.campaign_id, c.domain, c.news_type,c.url, c.active, c.article_date, c.created_date, c.modified_date, t.tr_title as title, t.language_id, t.tr_translated_date, t.tr_translated_by, t.translation_state';
        $where .=" AND t.translation_state = 1";
        if($queryv!='')
            $search = ' t.tr_title like "%'.mysql_real_escape_string($queryv).'%" ';
    }
    $whereCond.=$where;  

    $query->select($select)
          ->from('News c')
          ->leftJoin('c.TranslatedNews t')
          ->leftJoin('c.Campaigns eng')
           ->where($whereCond)
           ->addWhere('eng.tr_language_id=t.language_id')
           ->orderBy('c.'.$sortName. ' ' . $sortOrder)
          ->groupBy('c.title')
          ->addGroupBy('c.url');
        if(!empty($search))
            $query->addWhere($search);
         //echo $query->getSqlQuery();exit;
      /*
                          here when i output query and run in any query browser it works fine.
      */
           $pager = new Doctrine_Pager($query,$currentPage, $resultsPerPage);// here it fails to retrive data

    return $pager;//print_r($pager);exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of addWhere try to use andWhere()

Answer (score 0):

i have used example like this

```
 $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                            ->select('t.*')
                            ->from('TransferReason t');
            if ($searchValue != "") {
                $q->where($feildName.' LIKE ?', '%' . trim($searchValue) . '%');
            }
            $q->orderBy($orderField . ' ' . $orderBy);
```

Comment: i want to search string for example: testin'g for me it  search fine for single table, but when i join multiple tables it dosen't.

Answer (score 0):

here the join  example

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                                    ->from('TransferRequest t')
                                    ->leftJoin('t.Employee e ON t.emp_number = e.emp_number')
                                    ->leftJoin('e.CompanyStructure c ON e.work_station = c.id')
                                    ->where("c.title LIKE ?", "%{$cond}%");
```

Comment: yaa for me normal search (ex string: testing) works but when string contains single quote (ex string: testin'g)  in it, it dosen't works

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string function 


$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));

Comment: i used mysql_real_escape_string also but it dosent works for me please have a look at my query once

Comment: try to excute your query step by step then you will find the error

Comment: first try 

 $query->select($select)
          ->from('News c')
          ->leftJoin('c.TranslatedNews t')
          ->leftJoin('c.Campaigns eng')
           ->where($whereCond)  

only and see whether out put coming

Comment: query works fine until search string provided with single quote.other than that all other cases woks fine. I tried using mysql_real_escape_string() and with addslashes also but not working

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine handles escaping internally. Use a query like:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('MyTable m')->where('m.column = ?', '?´## \'´^#11 " dfvü:?=._ßß?(%%/');
```

And the characters will be escaped to be safe for your database.

Answer (score 0):

May problem is during joining because I always write like:

```
$query->select($select)
      ->from('News', 'c')
      ->leftJoin('c.TranslatedNews', 't')
      ->leftJoin('c.Campaigns', 'eng')
       ->where($whereCond)
       ->andWhere('eng.tr_language_id=t.language_id')
       ->orderBy('c.'.$sortName. ' ' . $sortOrder)
      ->groupBy('c.title, c.url');
    if(!empty($search))
        $query->addWhere($search);
```

I cant find $sortName and $sortOrder so maybe you are missing some variables.

I suggest using case instead of many if's for $where (less code lines :))